# Canonical Discriminant Function in Python sklearn

Tags: python, statistics, scikit-learn, pca, linear-discriminant

I am learning about Linear Discriminant Analysis and am using the scikit-learn module.  I am confused by the "coef_" attribute from the [LinearDiscriminantAnalysis](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis) class.  As far as I understand, these are the discriminant function coefficients (sklearn calls them weight vectors).  Since there should be (n_classes-1) discriminant functions, I would expect the coef_ attribute to be an array with shape (n_components, n_features), but instead it prints an (n_classes, n_features) array. Below is an example of this using the Iris dataset example from sklearn. Since there are 3 classes and 2 components, I would expect print(lda.coef_) to give me a 2x4 array instead of a 3x4 array...

Maybe I'm misinterpreting what the weight vectors are, perhaps they are the coefficients for the classification function?

And how do I get the coefficients for each variable in each discriminant/canonical function?

[screenshot of jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzeSA.png)

Code here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
import numpy as np

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
target_names = iris.target_names
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2,store_covariance=True)
X_r = lda.fit(X, y).transform(X)

plt.figure()
for color, i, target_name in zip(colors, [0, 1, 2], target_names):
    plt.scatter(X_r2[y == i, 0], X_r2[y == i, 1], alpha=.8, color=color,
                label=target_name)
plt.legend(loc='best', shadow=False, scatterpoints=1)
plt.xlabel('Function 1 (%.2f%%)' %(lda.explained_variance_ratio_[0]*100))
plt.ylabel('Function 2 (%.2f%%)' %(lda.explained_variance_ratio_[1]*100))
plt.title('LDA of IRIS dataset')

print(lda.coef_)
#output -> [[  6.24621637  12.24610757 -16.83743427 -21.13723331]
# [ -1.51666857  -4.36791652   4.64982565   3.18640594]
# [ -4.72954779  -7.87819105  12.18760862  17.95082737]]
```

Comment: The way I would read it is: `lda.coef_` gives you the weight of each attribute for each class

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the coefficients with the following code:

```
def LDA_coefficients(X,lda):
    nb_col = X.shape[1]
    matrix= np.zeros((nb_col+1,nb_col), dtype=int)
    Z=pd.DataFrame(data=matrix,columns=X.columns)
    for j in range(0,nb_col):
        Z.iloc[j,j] = 1
    LD = lda.transform(Z)
    nb_funct= LD.shape[1]
    results = pd.DataFrame();
    index = ['const']
    for j in range(0,LD.shape[0]-1):
        index = np.append(index,'C'+str(j+1))
    for i in range(0,LD.shape[1]):
        coef = [LD[-1][i]]
        for j in range(0,LD.shape[0]-1):
            coef = np.append(coef,LD[j][i]-LD[-1][i])
        result = pd.Series(coef)
        result.index = index
        column_name = 'LD' + str(i+1)
        results[column_name] = result
    return results
```

Before calling this function you need to complete the linear discriminant analysis:

```
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
lda.fit(X,y)
```